# How to find minimum column name by condition on values in R

Tags: r

I need minimum column name between column that has positive value.

```
set.seed(123)
dts=data.frame(matrix(rnorm(30), nrow = 10))
colnames(dts)=c('2','3','4')
```

for example for bellow data set last column is answer, how could I build it?

```
    2            3          4         answer
1  -0.56047565  1.2240818 -1.0678237 3
2  -0.23017749  0.3598138 -0.2179749 3
3   1.55870831  0.4007715 -1.0260044 2
4   0.07050839  0.1106827 -0.7288912 2
5   0.12928774 -0.5558411 -0.6250393 2
6   1.71506499  1.7869131 -1.6866933 2
7   0.46091621  0.4978505  0.8377870 2
8  -1.26506123 -1.9666172  0.1533731 4
9  -0.68685285  0.7013559 -1.1381369 3
10 -0.44566197 -0.4727914  1.2538149 4
```

Comment: there's some problem with column name. they can start what else 1. please edit your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
apply(dts, 1, function(i) names(dts[i > 0])[1])
#[1] "2" "2" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "3" "2" "3"
```

Answer (score 3):

We can also try with `max.col`

```
 max.col(-replace(dts, dts <0, 999), "first")
 #[1] 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 3 2 3
```

If we need the minimum column names

```
 max.col(-replace(col(dts), dts <0, 999), "first")
 #[1] 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 3 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you build a matrix with `col` values where `dts` is positive and `NA` everywhere else, you can `apply` `which.min` rowwise:

```
# the matrix to apply over
ifelse(dts > 0, col(dts), NA)
##        1  2  3
##  [1,] NA  2 NA
##  [2,] NA  2 NA
##  [3,]  1  2 NA
##  [4,]  1  2 NA
##  [5,]  1 NA NA
##  [6,]  1  2 NA
##  [7,]  1  2  3
##  [8,] NA NA  3
##  [9,] NA  2 NA
## [10,] NA NA  3

# apply which.min to each row
apply(ifelse(dts > 0, col(dts), NA), 1, which.min)
## [1] 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 3 2 3
```